# How to apply functions to elements in sub-lists nested in a list with sapply()?

Tags: r, nested-lists, sapply

I would like to replace this loop with one of the `*apply` family of functions. More generally, how to access arbitrarily deeply nested elements within lists using vectorized functions in R?

```
 frequencies <- vector(length = length(pops1_grouped))
      for(i in 1:length(pops1_grouped)){
        frequencies[i] <- sum(pops1_grouped[[i]]$frequency)
    }
```

My attempt at achieving this:

```
frequencies <- sapply(pops1_grouped, function(x) sum(x[[]]$frequency))
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but it was my best guess as of now.

Am I wrong in assuming one can access any level of nested element inside of a list within vectorized functions like `sapply()`?

I imagine others have answered this exact sort of question before, please feel free to direct me towards such threads, I just haven't been able to find the right answers in several searches so far.

Comment: Have you tried `sapply(pops1_grouped, \(x) sum(x$frequency))`?

Comment: Please post a data example using `dput`. Or code to create the list

Comment: @RuiBarradas I actually did, and must have overlooked the output, as I thought it output all 0's when I am expecting 1's. This does work though, thank you. Do you know if this method can be used for arbitrarily deeply nested elements?

Comment: For arbitrarily deeply nested lists, no, this wouldn't work. You would have to have a recursive algorithm, see `help("Recall")`.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten about `rapply(top_list, sum)`, with the recursive version of `lapply`.